# Why casting function type as AnyObject works

Tags: swift, anyobject

***Question :*** Difference between Any vs. AnyObject

**Answer :** 
**Any** can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types and optional types.

**AnyObject** can represent an instance of any class type.

I tried to store a function type in a Any and a AnyObject variables

```
func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
let funcType = add
let test1: Any = funcType
let test2: AnyObject = funcType//Value of type '(Int, Int) -> Int' does not conform to specified type 'AnyObject' Insert ' as AnyObject'
```

When I use the fix option

```
let test2: AnyObject = funcType as AnyObject
```

It works without any error. How am I able to store a function type in a AnyObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes `as AnyObject` converts the casted value to an Objective-C compatible one: `Int`'s become `NSNumber`, array's become `NSArray`, and so on. Swift-only values get wrapped within opaque `SwiftValue` instances.

```swift
print(type(of: test2)) // __SwiftValue
```

This is why adding `as AnyObject` makes your code compile, as the right-hand of the operator is now an object.

Comment: I know _"Int's become NSNumber, array's become NSArray"_ Thanks for explaining the _Swift-only values_ thing